# Which type of Spring Integration Channel?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I have a queue in ActiveMQ and would like to take the messages off it, into our application using spring integration. We have the application deployed twice (in case one of them fails) - each message should be processed by only one of the applications. In addition I need a jms tx manager in case of fatal application failure during message processing. As such my channel adapter looks like this:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter 
    channel="myChannel" 
    connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
    pub-sub-domain="false"
    destination-name="MY_QUEUE" 
    transaction-manager="jmsTxManager" />
```

This all works fine when `myChannel` is a direct channel, however I'd like to use a task executor so that many messages can be processed at once.

In order to cater for fatal application failure I thought a rendezvous channel might be the way to go (I believed that when a thread became free in the task executor the channel adapter would go away to active mq to retrieve another message) as there wouldn't be any messages held in memory on the channel. This doesn't seem to work, and the following code throws `TaskRejectException`:

```
<int:channel id="myChannel">
    <int:rendezvous-queue />
</int:channel>
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="2" queue-capacity="0" />
<int:router input-channel="myChannel" expression="payload.getType() + 'Channel'">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
</int:router>
```

The service activators that sit after the router, processing synchronously, take 10 seconds to process so I'd expect at t=0s to go away and retrieve 2 messages (the size of the thread pool), process them, release the thread to the thread pool at t=10s, then request a message from active mq again. It seems however that more than 2 messages are retrieved at t=0s.

Can anyone advise on what I should be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for transactions to work, you MUST use direct channels.

You can control the number of concurrent threads using the concurrency attributes on the `message-driven-channel-adapter` (`concurrent-consumers` and `max-concurrent-consumers`).